# why does one code compiles and the other fails?

Tags: c++

This code complies:

```
template <class T>
class A {};

void main () {

    A<int> a;
    vector<A<int>> vec;
    vec.push_back(a);
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
void main () {

    SharedPointer<int> sp;
    vector<SharedPointer<int>> vec;
    vec.push_back(sp);
}
```

I get this error:

> error C2558: class 'SharedPointer' : no copy constructor available
>   or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'

SharedPointer header: (all methodes are implemented in the header)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Myexception.h"
using namespace std;

#pragma once

template<class T>
class SharedPointer {
    T* ob;
    int* refcount;
    bool shareable;

    int refdown();
    int refup();
    void markUnshareable();
public:

    virtual ~SharedPointer();
    SharedPointer():shareable(true);
    SharedPointer(T pointee):shareable(true);
    SharedPointer(SharedPointer<T>& sp);
    SharedPointer operator=(const SharedPointer<T>& sp);
    bool operator==(const SharedPointer<T>& sp);
    const T& operator[](const int idx) const;
    T& operator[](const int idx);
    T* operator->() const;
    T& operator*() const;
    void setOb(T pointee);
    const T& getOb() const;
    int getRefcount();
    bool isShareable();
    bool isShared();
};
```

Comment: I have never seen `SharedPointer():shareable(true);` this before. Are you sure it compiles? What compiler are you using?

Comment: To expand upon RedX's point, I believe the initialisation list (`:shareable(true)`) is part of the definition (not declaration) of the ctor, so you either need the complete definition (e.g. move constructor body to header, even if empty (`SharedPointer():shareable(true) {};`)) or move initialisation list to cpp with the the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the copy constructor:

```
SharedPointer(SharedPointer<T>& sp);
```

can't only be used to copy a `const` pointer. Add the missing `const` and all should be fine:

```
SharedPointer(const SharedPointer& sp);   // <T> is harmless, but unnecessary
```

(You'll also have to fix the syntax errors in the constructor definitions, and you should change the return type of `main` to `int`. Removing `using namespace std;` would also be a good idea.)

Comment: `using namespace std;` in `SharedPointer.h` probably means it won't be "fine".  ;)

Comment: Ant the `<T>` isn't needed.

Comment: @BrianCain: It's a bad idea, but probably fine until you accidentally reuse one of the standard library's names.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor declared

```
SharedPointer(SharedPointer<T>& sp);
```

should look like :

```
SharedPointer(const SharedPointer<T>& sp);
```

so the compiler will find the missing copy constructor